# Assign nested object in react

Tags: reactjs, javascript-objects

im working on a project and im really stuck with a problem, im doing a form to upload dwellings, im assinging the data to an object, the problem is i want to create a nested object, and im getting some weird errors.

```
   constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {dwelling: new Dwelling()};
    }

    handleChange({target: {id, value}}) {
        console.log(id);
        console.log(value);
        this.setState(
            state => ({
                dwelling: (Object.assign(state.dwelling.spaces, {[id]: value}))
            })
        );
        console.log(this.state.dwelling.spaces.dorms);
    }

    render() {
        const {dwelling} = this.state;
        return (
            <Grid className="animated fadeIn">
                <Row>
                    <Col sm={12}>
                        <h2>Completar <b>Espacios</b></h2>
                        <Row>
                            <Col sm={2}>
                                <FormGroup controlId="dorms">
                                    <ControlLabel>Tipo de Publicación</ControlLabel>
                                    <FormControl
                                        componentClass="select"
                                        value={dwelling.spaces.dorms}
                                        onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)}
                                    >
                                        <option disabled label="Seleccione"/>
                                        <option value="Alquiler" label="Alquiler"/>
                                        <option value="Venta" label="Venta"/>
                                    </FormControl>
                                </FormGroup>
```

so on the hanlder i can access this.state.dwelling.spaces and it shows and object made of 2 propiertys dorms and closets:
Data model:

```
export default class Dwelling {
publicationType = '';
address = '';
type = '';
subtype = '';
currency = '';
price = '';

constructor(obj) {
    Object.assign(this, obj);
    this.spaces = {
        dorms: '',
        closets: ''
    };
}
```

EDIT: i changed the data model, but now i get the whole object replaced insted of only modfying the sub object

Answer (score 0):

You aren't assigning those variables in your `constructor` as part of `this`, so you aren't able to access any of them. Changing your `Dwelling` class to this should work.

```
constructor() {
    this.spaces={
        dorms: '',
        closets: ''
    };
}
```

`this.setState` is an asynchronous function. Your `console.log` runs before `this.state` updates. To make it synchronous with respect to the `console.log`, place it as a callback to `this.setState`

```
this.setState(
  state => ({
    dwelling: (Object.assign(state.dwelling.spaces, {[id]: value}))
  }), () => console.log(this.state.dwelling.spaces.dorms);
);
```

Comment: same problem, the console log dosent show any error or anything, just a blank line.

Comment: @NicolasAlbarracin Is it a blank line or `undefined`? If it's the former, isn't that what it's supposed to be? It's assigned as an empty string.

Comment: its a blank line

Comment: @NicolasAlbarracin Updated. I think you're talking about the `console.log` I explain. If it's not, give me a heads up.

Comment: i changed the model to your advice, my problem is now the object asign replaces the whole object, i end up with dwellings.dorms with the data insted of dwelling.spaces.dorms